# Microchip ICSP PIC 32F Programming with ICD3- Secure Chip Vs Verify

Tags: microchip

A hex file is provided to the Microchip IPE programming tool and an ICD3 for a PIC 32F. The hex file includes an out-of-memory-map data location with a config bit set that sets a configuration register so tha the contents of ROM cannot be read withut erasing the chip.

When Using Microchips IPE tool, will an ICD 3 actually verify the PIC 32F chip and then secure it, or will it simply program the chip blindly in one step since the chip cannot be read back.

Answer (score 1):

It will actually verify the chip, but it will program it bindly, believing that the hex is intended for that part.
The IPE checks for the appropriate part to set the fuses (config words). If it is on a different location than the assembled hex, you may run into problems like, for example, having a WDT running. So, if the hex was assembled for another part, it will work just the same.